# Prototype Js : How to iterate over some of the Json objects

Tags: javascript, json, prototypejs

How to iterate over this kind of Json object in Prototype Js ( not Jquery)

There are also sub objects with value indexs

I want to populate multi select box with given values.

```
data = object(
    0 => object(
        'label' = > 'test1',
        'value' = > 1
    ),
    1 => object(
        'label' = > 'test1',
        'value' = >
        0 = > object(
            'label' = > 'sub testing1',
            'value' = > 1
        ),
        1 = > object(
            'label' = > 'sub testing2',
            'value' = > 1
        ),
    ),
    3 = > object(
        'label' = > 'test3',
        'value' = >
        0 = > object(
            'label' = > 'sub testing - test 3',
            'value' = > 33
        ),
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Prototype in a while but try this:

```
data.each(function(i){
    console.log(i.label); // or whatever you need to do
});
```

Comment: I don't want one line code. i want to parse value and label to populate multiselect.

Comment: So go ahead and write that code. We're not going to do all of your work for you.

Comment: Don't be rude. Ok? you understand?

Comment: I didn't ask you to do that. OK. Get lost

Comment: @ShahidNajamAfridi - you understand this code does exactly what you are asking.  You are the one who is being rude.